# How to get specific attribute inside a tag of javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml, express

So I have this XML :

```
<enclosure length="25000" type="image/jpeg" url="https://www.hellothere.com/something.jpg"/>
```

and I have already converted it to a javascript object like this :

```
{
 title: (1) ["something"],
 enclosure: (1) [{...}]
}
```

I already watched it while debugging and the value is there, while it is **undefined**, everytime I try to access it.

When I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` it return this result :

```
"enclosure": [
      {
        "$": {
          "length": "25000",
          "type": "image/jpeg",
          "url": "https://hellothere.com/something.jpg"  
        }
      }
    ]
```

but when I do `console.log(data)` , it returns `undefined`

if we stretch it :

```
data :
 > title: (1) ['something here']
 > enclosure: (1) [{...}]
   > 0: {$: {...}}
    > $: {length='25000',type='image/jpeg',url='https://www.hellothere.com/something.jpg'}
      length: '25000'
      type: 'image/jpeg'
      url: 'https://www.hellothere.com/something.jpg'
```

In python, I tried using something like `data['enclosure']['@url']` and it works.
I've tried :

```
> data['enclosure'][0]['url']
> data['enclosure']['@url']
> data['enclosure']['$url']
```

but nothing worked.
How do I get the value of **url** in that **enclosure** tag ? Thank you

EDIT :

codes :

index.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 getJson.produce_data(url_source.url, function (err, data) {
  data = data["rss"]["channel"][0]["item"];
   if (err) {
     return console.error(err);
   }
   res.render('json_results', {title: 'NEWS TODAY', data_in: data});
 });
});
```

produce_data function :

```
function produce_data(url, callback) {
    var req = https.get(url, function(res) {
        var currentData = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            currentData += chunk;
        })

        res.on('error', function(err) {
            callback(err, null);
        })

        res.on('timeout', function(err) {
            callback(err, null);
        })

        res.on('end', function() {
            parsedtext(currentData , function(err, result) {
                callback(null, result);
            })
        });
    });
}
```

These are the lines of code that involved in the process.

Screenshot :

This is the data contained when in debug mode :

[image: data_contain]

[image: data_contain_2]

[image: data_contain_3]

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates the issue, e.g. an object literal example of whatever it is you've "already converted it to a javascript object" . None of the code above is valid javascript. `['enclosure'][0]` is an array literal with one element, the string "enclosure". `['enclosure'][0]` returns the string 'enclosure', then `'enclosure'['url']` returns *undefined* (unless you've extended *String.prototype* with a *url* property).

Comment: Kindly check the edited information above.

Answer (score 0):

Reconstructing the object from what looks like a console inspection and applying the following rules:

1. objects props are referenced by dot and the prop name
2. array elements are referenced by square braces and the index

so...

```js
let data = {
  title: ['something here'],
  enclosure: [{
    $: {
      length: '25000',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      url: 'https://www.hellothere.com/something.jpg'
    }
  }]
}

console.log(data.enclosure[0].$.url)
```

Comment: `data.enclosure[0].$.url` is the same as `data['enclosure'][0]['$']['url']` and it's not working. Still hitting same error

Answer (score 0):

Your enclosure property is an array so you have to refer to it by index:

```
let xml_obj = {
 title: ["something"],
 enclosure: [{
    length:'25000',type:'mage/jpeg',url:'https://www.hellothere.com/something.jpg'
 }]
}
//in this case there is one element so the index is zero!
alert(xml_obj.enclosure[0].url)
```

This is in JavaScript, you seem to be using both JS and Python in your project.

Comment: I've tried this, please refer on my tries above. This `xml_obj.enclosure[0].url` is the same as `data['enclosure'][0]['url']` (I tried this before). And I also tried your suggestion and still hit the same error. Yes, while it's working on Python, I can't seem get it around with JavaScript.

Comment: `data[0].enclosure[0].$.url`?

Comment: No, as $ is not seen as string. I also confused why is that. I've explained below on my answer and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't contain enough actual code to determine what you're doing, so the following is something of a guess.

You can [turn the XML into a document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString), then access the nodes and attributes using DOM methods, e.g.

```js
let xml = '<enclosure length="25000" type="image/jpeg" url="https://www.hellothere.com/something.jpg"/>';

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
let enclosures = doc.getElementsByTagName('enclosure');

for (let i=0, iLen=enclosures.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  console.log(`Node ${i} url: ${enclosures[i].getAttribute('url')}`);
}
```

Comment: I've edited the information above. Please refer above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this question is closed. I've found it.
Turns out I only have to add '$' because this symbol -> $ somehow behaves like a pointer (?). I didn't modify the content of XML and the $ is added itself.
So it's not a string.

If it's a string, the solutions above and provided has already solved it , but it doesn't.

Since my data is in an array, this line of code works :

```
data[sequence]['enclosure'][0]['\$']['url']
```